# Must I call super when I implement -scrollViewDidScroll: of UIScrollViewDelegate in an UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I made a custom UITableView subclass and implemented this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // scrolled...
}
```

Now, what I think is that UITableView may also love to get this message for some obvious reasons. However, when I don't forward that to super, for some reason, everything still works fine. Must I forward that guy to super? I mean...it's a delegate method implementation, but as far as I'm aware of, this would still override anything implemented in UITableView, or not?

Edit: I see...the delegate could be anyone. Never mind about this. BUT: What I have such a thing in a superclass, and make a subclass. How would I even know that the superclass does implement that method and I must forward it to super?

Comment: *How would I even know that the superclass does implement that method and I must forward it to super*  There is no way to know. It's infuriating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a delegate method which means it gets called by your instance of UITableView for your convenience.

The scrolling happens and the UITableView internal code will call.

```
if ([delegate respondsTo:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)]) {
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:) withObject:[self scrollView]];
}
```

And so you use this method to implement additional functionality, for example activating a control when the tableView has scrolled a certain amount.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.
Those methods are defined in the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol.
They are meant to be implemented in a delegate, which maybe only has NSObject as parent.

It does not override anything, as it's a delegate method.
The UIScrollView just does it's stuff, and calls the delegate method if a delegate is set.

Comment: One reason this might be confusing for some people is in the situation where you are working with a subclass of UITableViewController, which already implements this method, thus requiring you to prefix the function with the override keyword. However, the answer is still correct as it is very important NOT to call super in this circumstance. (Just pretend that super is not a thing.)